# What are upstream/downstream flows in the Kotlin language

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, terminology, kotlin-flow

In the [flow documentation](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/docs/flow.md#intermediate-flow-operators) they mentioned an upstream and a downstream flows:

> Flows can be transformed with operators, just as you would with collections and sequences. Intermediate operators are applied to an upstream flow and return a downstream flow.

Given code (from the same source):

```
(1..3).asFlow() // a flow of requests
        .map { request -> performRequest(request) }
        .collect { response -> println(response)
```

Do upstream and downstream mean an input and an output (a return value)? For example when the programming language starts to execute the `.map` part, a value of `(1..3).asFlow()` is an upstream flow and a return value of the `.map {...}` is a downstream flow?

Comment: cross-site duplicate of https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/402321/60171

Answer (score -3, accepted):

**Kotlin's oficial definition:**

`interface Flow<out T>`

An asynchronous data stream that sequentially emits values and completes normally or with an exception.

**Intermediate operators** on the flow such as **map, filter, take, zip**, etc are **functions** that are applied to the **upstream flow or flows** and **return a downstream flow** where further operators can be applied to. Intermediate operations do not execute any code in the flow and are not suspending functions themselves. They only set up a chain of operations for future execution and quickly return. This is known as a cold flow property.

**Terminal operators** on the flow are either suspending functions such as **collect, single, reduce, toList**, etc. or launchIn operator that starts collection of the flow in the given scope. They are applied to the upstream flow and trigger execution of all operations. Execution of the flow is also called collecting the flow and is always performed in a suspending manner without actual blocking. Terminal operators complete normally or exceptionally depending on successful or failed execution of all the flow operations in the upstream. The most basic terminal operator is collect, for example:

```
try {
    flow.collect { value ->
        println("Received $value")
    }
} catch (e: Exception) {
    println("The flow has thrown an exception: $e")
}
```

Comment: This is wrong. You can have more than two operators in a chain, in which case some of the upstream flows will be intermediate, not the source of data. Also, we do not consume data in a downstream flow. Data is consumed in a terminal operation, which does not produce another flow. Upstream and downstream are *relative* terms. A flow can be both upstream and downstream, depending on which other flow in the chain you are speaking about.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).